# mysql return default value 0 on SUM when there are no results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck on a query when I add the where clause. As expected I get no results so SUM has nothing to work with. I try to return a default value 0 for countSend and countPending when no rows are matching the where statement.

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN orders.status = "send" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) countSend,
  SUM(CASE WHEN orders.status = "pending" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) countPending
FROM orders
  LEFT OUTER JOIN order_posts AS op ON op.order_id = orders.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN posts AS p ON p.id = op.post_id
WHERE (orders.id LIKE "%Shop 3%") OR (p.title LIKE "%Shop 3%")
  GROUP BY orders.id
  LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  You are aggregating by a column, but not including it in the `SELECT`, which seems odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish, but the `GROUP BY` may not be necessary.  The following will always return one row:

```
SELECT SUM(o.status = 'send') as countSend,
       SUM(o.status = 'pending') as countPending
FROM orders o LEFT OUTER JOIN
     order_posts op
     ON op.order_id = o.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     posts p
     ON p.id = op.post_id
WHERE (o.id LIKE '%Shop 3%') OR (p.title LIKE '%Shop 3%');
```

If the `WHERE` clause filters everything out, you will still get one row, with `NULL` values.  Use `COALESCE()` to return `0` instead:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(o.status = 'send'), 0) as countSend,
       COALESCE(SUM(o.status = 'pending'), 0) as countPending
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `coalesce()` which will return the value the first expression evaluates to, when that value isn't `NULL` or the value of the second expression. (This also goes on for more than two expressions but in your case it's only two).

```
SELECT coalesce(sum(CASE
                      WHEN orders.status = "send" THEN
                        1
                      ELSE
                        0
                    END),
                0) countSend,
       coalesce(sum(CASE
                      WHEN orders.status = "pending" THEN
                        1
                      ELSE
                        0
                    END),
                0) countPending
...
```